# Android: MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener()

Tags: android, runnable, android-mediaplayer

I've got a Service, which implements `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener`.

Until now I called `player.setOnPreparedListener(this)` inside a function and it worked well. Now I want to call `setOnPreparedListener` from `Runnable` (using a `Handler`), but I get error :

> The method setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener) in
>   the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   Runnable(){})

So instead of `this` I would need to use something that would point to current `class`. The question is, which `class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(MyService.this);
```

In your Handler, `this` obviously refers to the Handler. By using `MyService.this` you force the `this` keyword a scope higher, referencing the `Context` of the `Activity`.

Comment: It should probably say "MyService.this", as it's a service that implements the listener, but yes, +1.

Comment: No need to. If you don't know, you don't know ;)

Answer (score 9):

I assume that when you called `player.setOnPreparedListener(this)`, your activity implemented `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener`. And your `Runnable` isn't (of course). There are two options:

1. If this runnable is implemented inside the activity, use the fully qualified `this`: `YourActivity.this`
2. If not, you can implement this listener in just the point of the call:

   ```
   player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       // do stuff here
       }
   }
   ```